# Equality condition on a double loop variable: unspecified or undefined?

Tags: c++, precision, undefined-behavior, unspecified-behavior

I would like to get straight on terminology. Consider:

```
for (double d = 0.0; d != 1.0; d += 0.1)
    cout << d << " ";
```

If I understand correctly, since double arithmetic is imprecise, this loop can be either finite or infinite. Is this considered unspecified or undefined behavior?

Comment: No, it's not unspecified or undefined behavior, it's simply how floating point numbers work. Due to the rounding errors, `d != 1.0` can be `true` even if `d` "should" be `1.0`, and also `d` will stop increasing at some point once it is so big that the +0.1 will be rounded down.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behaviour of your program is [implementation defined](http://eel.is/c++draft/defns.impl.defined): Different implementations can have different behavior, but they must document it. This is different from [unspecified behavior](http://eel.is/c++draft/defns.unspecified) (need not be documented) and [undefined behavior](http://eel.is/c++draft/defns.undefined) (anything goes). See also [Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior?rq=1).

A common implementation of `double` is defined by IEEE754. If that standard is followed by your implementation, then that loop will always recover the same output.

Your loop is infinite under IEEE754 - you'll skip over `1.0` and eventually `d` will grow to such a size where adding `0.1` is a no-op.

Comment: ...for the same binary, floating point environment settings, OS and hardware. If any of them change you might not get the same output.

Comment: @MaxLanghof: No, I think that's all in the IEEE754 spec. Although an implementation might not implement it faithfully (e.g. non-strict FP).

Comment: I'm not sure that's true, IEEE754 specifies several rounding modes at least: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Rounding_modes. But yes, for simple arithmetic like this the OS and hardware might be irrelevant as long as the rounding mode is constant (and the compiler is compliant).

Comment: Wikipedia says: "Unspecified behavior is behavior that may vary on different implementations of a programming language." How is *implementation defined* different from *unspecified behavior*?

Comment: "Implementation defined" means the implementation has to explicitly define what it's going to do. Unspecified behaviour means the implementation doesn't have to specify (i.e. document) the behaviour.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning See also [`[defns.impl.defined]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/defns.impl.defined), [`[defns.unspecified]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/defns.unspecified), and [`[defns.undefined]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/defns.undefined).

Comment: @MaxLanghof: That's gotta be a candidate for "comment of the day". If only you could pass a bounty to a comment.

Comment: @Bathsheba Thanks! (Even though I wouldn't consider it really noteworthy :D) Feel free to add it to your answer if you want!

Comment: @MaxLanghof: I've wiki'd the answer so you can make the edits as you please.

Comment: @Bathsheba: The Standard is deliberately vague as to the level of detail with which behaviors must be specified.  If it would be expensive to make a behavior behave precisely consistently, and if such consistency would have little value for some kinds of applications, an implementation shouldn't be required to behave consistently.